# sending value of hidden input to state react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this:

```
 const { siteLocation, Services, date, cnum } = this.state;

  const selections = {
    siteLocation,
    Services,
    date,
    cnum,
  };
```

and this:

```
 <p className="Services">
    <input name="Services" type="text" className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="Services" placeholder="Services" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
 </p>
            
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value={Date().toLocaleString()} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

however, the services one works, on change it sets it into the state, but the one with the hidden type, and `date` name, doesn't change. how do I send the value of the hidden tag into the state?

Comment: Do you only need to send it when you submitting all the fields? Then wrap them inside a <form/> and use onSubmit prop from it. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Comment: @RyanLe I actually just thought of that. thank you :)